# What is the point implementing custom math functions in C++ (like SQRT)?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

In the past few weeks I was wondering what is the point that people trying to re-invent the wheel and spend hours to write their own sqrt function for example. The built-in version is optimized well, precise and stable enough.

I am speaking about the Carmack-style Square Root for example. What is the point? It will lose precision during the approximation and it uses casting.

Intel style SSE Square Root was giving precise results, but was slower in my calculations than the standard SQRT.

By average, all the above tricks were beaten by far the standard SQRT. So my question is, what is the point?

My PC has the below CPU:

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz.

I've got the following results for each method (I've fixed the performance test according to the below suggestion by the helpful comment, thanks for that n.m.):

(Please keep in mind that if you're using approximation like Newton method, you'll lose precision so you must align your calculation accordingly.)

[image]

You can find the source code below for reference.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <deque>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <random>

using f64 = double;
using s64 = int64_t;
using u64 = uint64_t;

static constexpr u64 cycles = 24;
static constexpr u64 sample_max = 1000000;

f64 sse_sqrt(const f64 x) {
    __m128d root = _mm_sqrt_pd(_mm_load_pd(&x));
    return *(reinterpret_cast<f64*>(&root));
}

constexpr f64 carmack_sqrt(const f64 x) {
    union {
        f64 x;
        s64 i;
    } u = {};
    u.x = x;
    u.i = 0x5fe6eb50c7b537a9 - (u.i >> 1);
    f64 xhalf = 0.5 * x;
    u.x = u.x * (1.5 - xhalf * u.x * u.x);
    # u.x = u.x * (1.5 - xhalf * u.x * u.x);
    # u.x = u.x * (1.5 - xhalf * u.x * u.x);
    # ... so on, if you want more precise result ...
    return u.x * x;
}

int main(int /* argc */, char ** /*argv*/) {
    std::random_device r;
    std::default_random_engine e(r());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<f64> dist(1, sample_max);
    std::deque<f64> samples(sample_max);
    for (auto& sample : samples) {
        sample = dist(e);
    }

    // std sqrt
    {
        std::cout << "> Measuring std sqrt.\r\n> Please wait . . .\r\n";
        f64 result = 0;
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (auto cycle = 0; cycle < cycles; ++cycle) {
            for (auto& sample : samples) {
                result += std::sqrt(static_cast<f64>(sample));
            }
        }
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto dt = t2 - t1;
        std::cout << "> Accumulated result: " << std::setprecision(19) << result << "\n";
        std::cout << "> Total execution time: " <<
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(dt).count() << " ms.\r\n\r\n";
    }

    // sse sqrt
    {
        std::cout << "> Measuring sse sqrt.\r\n> Please wait . . .\r\n";
        f64 result = 0;
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (auto cycle = 0; cycle < cycles; ++cycle) {
            for (auto& sample : samples) {
                result += sse_sqrt(static_cast<f64>(sample));
            }
        }
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto dt = t2 - t1;
        std::cout << "> Accumulated result: " << std::setprecision(19) << result << "\n";
        std::cout << "> Total execution time: " <<
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(dt).count() << " ms.\r\n\r\n";
    }

    // carmack sqrt
    {
        std::cout << "> Measuring carmack sqrt.\r\n> Please wait . . .\r\n";
        f64 result = 0;
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (auto cycle = 0; cycle < cycles; ++cycle) {
            for (auto& sample : samples) {
                result += carmack_sqrt(static_cast<f64>(sample));
           }
        }
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto dt = t2 - t1;
        std::cout << "> Accumulated result: " << std::setprecision(19) << result << "\n";
        std::cout << "> Total execution time: " <<
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(dt).count() << " ms.\r\n\r\n";
    }

    std::cout << "> Press any key to exit . . .\r\n";
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that I am not here for criticizing anybody, I am just here for learning, experimenting and trying to figure out my own method and the best toolset to choose from.

I am writing my own game engine to one of my portfolio. I am appreciating your kind answers and I am open for any suggestions.

Have a nice day.

Comment: floating point maths is not exact and there is never only one way to obtain the result, thus you always need to make a compromise, different implementations may give more weight to speed, others to precision. What is "precise and stable enough" depends on your application

Comment: I guess it's hard to say something in general, but reasons for implementing your own algorithm can be (1) for educational purposes / for fun; (2) to optimize for a specific piece of hardware or (3) to optimize for a specific application (e.g. if you only need 1/sqrt(x) for normalization of vectors - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)

Comment: You are measuring performance in a totally wrong way, and the figures you have arrived at are meaningless. Your result consists largely of the overhead of calling `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();`. In addition, you are doing nothing to eliminate the possibility of the compiler constant-folding and/or discarding all of your sqrt computations. [Here](https://ideone.com/f0dIA8) is hopefully somewhat more correct implementation of your test.

Comment: In case of `sqrt` and `pow` specifically, the historical reason for rolling these out manually is to get fixed point integer arithmetic. Traditionally, compilers haven't been able to optimize these functions into fixed point. Such optimizations is a relatively new thing. It is a shortcoming of the standard not to provide `int` alternatives.

Comment: @user463035818 it is tested on windows only, but the long term goal is to make the code cross-platform. The CMake project layout is already done, but I haven't tried on Android for example...

Comment: @n.m. I thought that C++ compiler will discard any useless function call if a specific flag is enabled. The code was compiled using with the lowest possible optimization setting ( -O0 flag) . I measured time as if I were writing a game loop with time sync. If chrono had such huge overhead, I believe most of the game loops that uses chrono would be trash. Timing is key for games, so I think they should be efficient or they should be.

Comment: Measuring performance of unoptimised code is a **waste of time**.

Comment: @n.m. Point taken. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I fixed my performance test suggested by n.m. Thanks for the suggestion! I've got a different result where carmack's method were the winner. But the difference is quite small. So if you have standard library available, then you can use std::sqrt, since it gives more precise result. But of course, everything depends on the underlying hardware (CPU in this case).

Comment: Old hardware was the problem.  In Carmack's days PCs did not yet have a math co-processor.  The trouble with floating precision due to the 80-bit internal format of the FPU is not quite in the past yet.  Looks like you might use a compiler that has the /fp compile option to work around that kind of hassle.  SSE fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For fun and profit?

Based on your question, there is no reason to do so, but if you want to learn a language, it is recommended to solve mathematical problems, because they rely on integers/floats (which are primitives in (mostly) any language) and the algorithms are well documented.

In "real" code, one should use the provided methods by libc as long as you have one. Embedded platforms usually lack of a libc or roll their own, so you have to implement your own.

Comment: Doing aggressive floating-point math is more an exercise in understanding floating-point math than in understanding any programming language. <g> +1.

Answer (score 9):

That fast reciprocal square root trick is mostly obsolete. SSE's built in approximate reciprocal square root which exists since the Pentium 3 has completely replaced it on the PC platform. Other platforms usually have their own reciprocal square root, for example ARM has `VRSQRTE` and a handy instruction that does the Newton step too.

By the way, turning the result into a non-reciprocal square root usually makes it less useful: the primary use case is normalizing a vector, where a "straight" square root is annoying (it would have to be divided by) while a reciprocal square root fits exactly (then it's a multiply).

As often, your benchmark isn't quite accurate. I happen to have done some relevant tests a while ago, where the relevant parts look like this:

`std::sqrt` based:

```
HMM_INLINE float HMM_LengthVec4(hmm_vec4 A)
{
    float Result = std::sqrt(HMM_LengthSquaredVec4(A));

    return(Result);
}

HMM_INLINE hmm_vec4 HMM_NormalizeVec4(hmm_vec4 A)
{
    hmm_vec4 Result = {0};

    float VectorLength = HMM_LengthVec4(A);

    /* NOTE(kiljacken): We need a zero check to not divide-by-zero */
    if (VectorLength != 0.0f)
    {
        float Multiplier = 1.0f / VectorLength;

#ifdef HANDMADE_MATH__USE_SSE
        __m128 SSEMultiplier = _mm_set1_ps(Multiplier);
        Result.InternalElementsSSE = _mm_mul_ps(A.InternalElementsSSE, SSEMultiplier);        
#else 
        Result.X = A.X * Multiplier;
        Result.Y = A.Y * Multiplier;
        Result.Z = A.Z * Multiplier;
        Result.W = A.W * Multiplier;
#endif
    }

    return (Result);
}
```

SSE reciprocal square root plus Newton step:

```
HMM_INLINE hmm_vec4 HMM_NormalizeVec4_new(hmm_vec4 A)
{
    hmm_vec4 Result;
    // square elements and add them together, result is in every lane
    __m128 t0 = _mm_mul_ps(A.InternalElementsSSE, A.InternalElementsSSE);
    __m128 t1 = _mm_add_ps(t0, _mm_shuffle_ps(t0, t0, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 3, 0, 1)));
    __m128 sq = _mm_add_ps(t1, _mm_shuffle_ps(t1, t1, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 1, 2, 3)));
    // compute reciprocal square root with Newton step for ~22bit accuracy
    __m128 rLen = _mm_rsqrt_ps(sq);
    __m128 half = _mm_set1_ps(0.5);
    __m128 threehalf = _mm_set1_ps(1.5);
    __m128 t = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_mul_ps(sq, half), _mm_mul_ps(rLen, rLen));
    rLen = _mm_mul_ps(rLen, _mm_sub_ps(threehalf, t));
    // multiply elements by the reciprocal of the vector length
    __m128 normed = _mm_mul_ps(A.InternalElementsSSE, rLen);
    // normalize zero-vector to zero, not to NaN
    __m128 zero = _mm_setzero_ps();
    Result.InternalElementsSSE = _mm_andnot_ps(_mm_cmpeq_ps(A.InternalElementsSSE, zero), normed);

    return (Result);
}
```

SSE reciprocal square root *without* Newton step:

```
HMM_INLINE hmm_vec4 HMM_NormalizeVec4_lowacc(hmm_vec4 A)
{
    hmm_vec4 Result;
    // square elements and add them together, result is in every lane
    __m128 t0 = _mm_mul_ps(A.InternalElementsSSE, A.InternalElementsSSE);
    __m128 t1 = _mm_add_ps(t0, _mm_shuffle_ps(t0, t0, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 3, 0, 1)));
    __m128 sq = _mm_add_ps(t1, _mm_shuffle_ps(t1, t1, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 1, 2, 3)));
    // compute reciprocal square root without Newton step for ~12bit accuracy
    __m128 rLen = _mm_rsqrt_ps(sq);
    // multiply elements by the reciprocal of the vector length
    __m128 normed = _mm_mul_ps(A.InternalElementsSSE, rLen);
    // normalize zero-vector to zero, not to NaN
    __m128 zero = _mm_setzero_ps();
    Result.InternalElementsSSE = _mm_andnot_ps(_mm_cmpeq_ps(A.InternalElementsSSE, zero), normed);

    return (Result);
}
```

([quick-bench](http://quick-bench.com/_Bi1xgyprf-Y08NiOPQJoXzNKl4))

[image: results]

As you can see I measured throughput and latency separately, and the distinction mattered a lot. Reciprocal square root with a Newton step takes a long time, about as long as using a normal square root, but can be processed at a higher throughput. Without Newton step, a single vector-normalize operation takes less time from start to finish too, and the throughput becomes even better than before. Anyway this should demonstrate that there is some point to doing something about your square roots.

By the way the above code is not meant to be Good Practice, that would be normalizing 4 vectors simultaneously, so as to not waste a 4-wide SIMD operation on calculating a *single* (reciprocal) square root. That's not really the issue here though.

Comment: If you are calculating square root in shaders, then this square root trick is not obsolete and it is quite good. But in case of C++, yes and it seems so.

Comment: @RajmundKail in shaders you also have `inversesqrt` (GLSL) and `rsqrt` (HLSL) and `rsq` (SM4 ASM) etc

Comment: Which one is the fastest one? Or the performance depends on the underlying gpu too?

Answer (score 6):

The point of [Carmack’s technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) was to extract better performance from integer operations than could be got from floating-point operations in the 1990’s. Since that time, floating point performance has massively improved! As you can see in your own benchmarks. There would be no practical reason to use that technique in new code unless you faced a similar constraint in your hardware, which the i7 doesn’t.

Comment: Not least because, back in the 90's, not every PC _had_ hardware floating point.

Comment: The i7 name goes back to µarchs with a slower square root too, such as Nehalem where it could still take around 30 cycles, and every square root had to wait until the previous one was completed. Skylake i7 is totally different, square root takes half the time and the throughput is even better. "i7" is not the part that matters.

Comment: I am referring to targeting a CPU with no FPU such as a 486SX. That’s the only modern use case for this technique. But thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: @Roger: All of the Id Software games starting with Quake requires a real FPU. Quake relied heavily on floating-point math.

Comment: Modern ARM Cortex M don't necessarily have FPU either. Most smaller microcontrollers don't.

Answer (score 6):

#### Limitation of standard library usage due to scope of project

> What is the point implementing custom math functions in C++ (like SQRT)?

In addition to what has already been mentioned in the other answers, the choice of a project implementing their own (custom) math functions could be due to:

- Limitations placed on the project, e.g. due to some standard, to not make use of the math library shipped with the compiler.

One example could be an [ASIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automotive_Safety_Integrity_Level) classified project adhering to [the ISO 26262 Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_26262), say, making use of a compiler that provides adequate qualification w.r.t. *correctly compiling the project's source code*, but that does not provide adequate qualification for *the shipped standard library*, where e.g. the math library could be linked in only by object and not source code (for the latter, appropriate tests and source code qualification could be written by the project themselves).

Comment: For SIL/ASIL you would be rolling out your own versions of all used library functions, for the sake of getting MISRA-C compliant code. I don't know of any existing, pre-qualified standard library.

Comment: Notably, there is no such thing as "SIL qualified compiler", that's just quackery, as the SIL standards don't provide any information about how such a qualification should be carried out. It only says that the tools must follow an international standard, such as ISO 9899 in case of C. For which there exists no sensible procedure of qualification. Mostly this is just fluff that has been lobbied into the SIL standards by compiler vendors. And if SIL qualification equals standard compliance, my money is on gcc over Wind River et al.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for your feedback. I guess "tool qualification" is a commonly mis-used word in this context (by the vendors), but at least if adhering to ISO 26262:2011, then Part 8, Section 11, contains some supporting processes regarding deriving a tool confidence level (TCL) based on tool impact (TI) and tool error detection (TD). E.g. an arbitrary compiler would arguably be a TCL3, where Table 4 of Section 11.4.6 (_Qualification of a SW tool_) recommends which methods to apply for qualification of the tool. But as this is all listed under _Supporting processes_, I agree it's a bit thin.